# WPF Best way to add generated Content

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel, itemsource

currently do it like this:

```xml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2">
  <ListBox Name="lb_right"  Background="Red">
    <ListBox.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Textfeld_Template}">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
          <Label Content="{Binding name}"></Label>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
          <Label Foreground="Red" IsEnabled="{Binding Pflicht}">Pflichtfeld!</Label>
        </WrapPanel>
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Datefeld_Template}">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
          <Label Content="{Binding name}"></Label>
          <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding zeit,StringFormat='dd.MMM.yyyy'}"></DatePicker>
          <Label Foreground="Red" IsEnabled="{Binding Pflicht}">Pflichtfeld!</Label>
        </WrapPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

For filling I use

```
ObservableCollection<Object> t = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
```

and set it to the Itemsource of listview, works fine, but, it is a listview, is there a Element with Itemsource like Wrappanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks, i found the Solution: ItemsControl (never used/saw it before)

```
<ItemsControl Name="lb_right"  Background="Red">


                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Textfeld_Template}">
                            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Label Content="{Binding name}"></Label>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
                            <Label Foreground="Red" IsEnabled="{Binding Pflicht}">Pflichtfeld!</Label>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Datefeld_Template}">
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Label Content="{Binding name}"></Label>
                                <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding zeit,StringFormat='dd.MMM.yyyy'}"></DatePicker>
                            <Label Foreground="Red" IsEnabled="{Binding Pflicht}">Pflichtfeld!</Label>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </ItemsControl>
```